# Boost sockets. Working code no longer working after format / reinstall of ubuntu. permission problems?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

i am running ubuntu 16.04 and using ROS kinetic (irrelevant for this question). unrelated to this project, i broke my system and decided to reinstall ubuntu. everything went fine and i thought that i had put my system back together. so now i have this code to send a packet to a LiDAR and decode the information i get back. you can see i put a couple cout's for debugging. the program freezes after sending the packet and waiting for the data back. this code has been working correctly for several months now and has not changed after the reinstall of ubuntu.

things i have tried

```
sudo adduser my_username dialout
sudo adduser my_username root
sudo adduser my_username sudo
```

I have also edited `/etc/sudoers.d` to add my username in there with all permissions.

the reason i suspect that the hangup is due to permissions is because i have another piece of code that uses UART communication through /dev/ttyUSB1 and i must use `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB1` before it will work. this was not necessary before.

The relevant code is below although i strongly suspect this is not the issue. the code compiles and runs as expected except for the hangup. i would appreciate any feedback and suggestions and i will do my best to keep on top of replies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;


class KeyenceLaser
{
    public:
        KeyenceLaser(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const std::string& host, const std::string& port):io_service_(io_service), socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0))
        {
            udp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
            udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), host, port);
            udp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
            endpoint_ = *iter;

            if (socket_.is_open()){std::cout<<"socket open"<<std::endl;;}else{std::cout<<"socket not open"<<std::endl;}
        }

        ~KeyenceLaser()
        {
            socket_.close();
        }

        void send(const std::string& msg) 
        {
            socket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg, msg.size()), endpoint_); 
        }
        void poll(sensor_msgs::LaserScan::Ptr scan) 
        {
            char request[1920];
                            char srequest[]={0x90,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};// sends the request to get all beam data back
            size_t request_length = strlen(srequest);
            unsigned char reply[1920];
            scan->ranges.resize(953);

            try
            {
std::cout<<"1 sending request"<<std::endl;
                boost::system::error_code errcode;
                boost::asio::socket_base::message_flags flags=NULL;
                int bytesSent =-1;
                bytesSent= socket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(srequest, 10), endpoint_ );
std::cout<<"sent " << bytesSent << " bytes\n2 waiting for data back"<<std::endl;
                size_t reply_length = socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(reply, 1920), endpoint_);
std::cout<<"3 got data back"<<std::endl;

                scan->angle_min = -.090757;
                scan->angle_max = 3.23234;
                scan->angle_increment = 3.323106 / 953.0;
                scan->range_min = 0.00;
                scan->range_max = 5.0;
                scan->ranges.reserve(953);
                scan->ranges.resize(953);
                scan->ranges.clear();

                for (int i=14;i < 1921; i++)
                    {
                    //std::cout << i/2-7<<":"<<(((reply[i+1]<<8) + reply[i])/1000.0) << std::endl;
                    scan->ranges.push_back(((reply[i+1]<<8) + reply[i])/1000.0);

                        i++;
                    }

            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
        udp::socket socket_;
        udp::endpoint endpoint_;
};
```

EDIT 1:

i have modified the code to the following...

```
std::cout<<"1 sending request"<<std::endl;
                    boost::system::error_code errcode;
                    boost::asio::socket_base::message_flags flags;
                    int bytesSent =-1;
                    bytesSent= socket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(srequest, 10), endpoint_ ,flags, errcode);
std::cout<<"sent " << bytesSent << " bytes\ngot error code: " << errcode << "\n2 waiting for data back"<<std::endl;
                    size_t reply_length = socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(reply, 1920), endpoint_);
std::cout<<"3 got data back"<<std::endl;
```

and i get error 95 - operation not supported , but i think thats cause i didnt instantiate my flags correctly (and google isnt helping me do that)

EDIT 2:

i just wanted to make it clear that i think i've installed all the required software. i'm open to apt-get some more stuff if you think that i'm just missing some library.
P.S. i did modify the code again slightly and the socket is being shown as open with 10 bytes sent. the LiDAR "link" light does not blink after i send the packet though (it did before), so I don't think the packet is actually getting through the cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this issue was unrelated to Boost Sockets. The error came from the connection to the LiDAR itself. It showed as connected via my network connections but it was not actually connected to the LiDAR. After I switched that conecttion IPv4 method to Link-Local, it worked immediately.thank you to everyone who read and considered my issue